# Output human readable time

Tags: javascript, datetime

I wrote a little function which formats a ms timestamp in a human readable way. I know there are lots of scripts out there, but I needed a very simple one, which only outputs minutes and hours.

I was wondering if there is any way to shorten or improve this code snippet, because to me it seems to be very long for the few things it actually does.

```
function prettyTime(ms) {
      var sec = ms / 1000,
          time,
          timeUnit;

      if(sec > 3600) {
          // Hours
          time = Math.round(sec / 3600);
          timeUnit = ' hr';
      } else if(sec > 60) {
          // Minutes
          time = Math.round(sec / 60);
          timeUnit = ' min';
      } else {
          return 'less than 1 min';  
      }

      if(time > 1) {
          timeUnit += 's';   
      }

      return 'about ' + time + timeUnit + 'ago';
}

alert(prettyTime(7600001));
```

Comment: One of the scripts out there is [fromNow using moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hope this might be helpful -

```
function getRelativeTime(ms){
    var SECOND_MS = 1000;
    var MINUTE_MS = 60 * SECOND_MS;
    var HOUR_MS = 60 * MINUTE_MS;
    var DAY_MS = 24 * HOUR_MS;
    var WEEK_MS = 7 * DAY_MS;
    var MONTH_MS = 30 * DAY_MS;

    var lookup = ["months", "weeks", "days", "hours", "minutes", "seconds"];
    var values = [];
    values.push(ms / MONTH_MS); ms %= MONTH_MS;
    values.push(ms / WEEK_MS); ms %= WEEK_MS;
    values.push(ms / DAY_MS); ms %= DAY_MS;
    values.push(ms / HOUR_MS); ms %= HOUR_MS;
    values.push(ms / MINUTE_MS); ms %= MINUTE_MS;
    values.push(ms / SECOND_MS); ms %= SECOND_MS;

    var pretty = "about "; 
    for(var i=0 ; i <values.length; i++){
        var val = Math.round(values[i]);
        if(val <= 0) continue;

        pretty += val + " " + lookup[i] + " ago";
        break;
    }
    return pretty;
}


getRelativeTime(10000);
```

Output :

```
about 10 seconds ago
```

You can easily customize above code for your "xx hours and xx mins ago" use-case. Just change the for loop like this -

```
for(var i=0 ; i <values.length; i++){
    var val = Math.round(values[i]);
    if(val <= 0) continue;

    pretty += val + " " + lookup[i];

    var nextval = Math.round(values[i+1]);
    if(i+1 < values.length && nextval > 0){
      pretty += " and " + nextval + " " + lookup[i+1] + " ago";
    }
    else {
      pretty += " ago";
    }
    break;
}
```

Output

getRelativeTime(100000);

```
about 2 minutes and 40 seconds ago
```

getRelativeTime(1000000);

```
about 17 minutes and 40 seconds ago
```

**UPDATE:**

> `Math.round` is causing wrong result in above code, `Math.floor` is more
>   appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot cleaner to me, although I think `var SECOND = 1;` should be var `SECOND = 1000;`, shouldn't it? Is there any elegant way to use 'less than a minute ago' instead of seconds?

Comment: You're right, updated the code.

Comment: IMO, `SECOND`, `MINUTE`, etc. should be named `SECOND_MS`, `MINUTE_MS`, and so on so it's clear what units they're in.

Comment: Makes sense, you got it!